# lwap She tirst fetters!

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a list or delimited string, output a list or delimited string with the first character of each word one word later.

For this challenge, a "word" consists of only all printable ASCII characters, except the space, newline, and tab character.

For example, take the string "Good afternoon, World!" (space-delimited):

```
1. String
"Good afternoon, World!"

2. Get the first characters:
"[G]ood [a]fternoon, [W]orld!"

3. Move the characters over. The character at the end gets moved to the beginning.
"[W]ood [G]fternoon, [a]orld!"

4. Final string
"Wood Gfternoon, aorld!"
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

**Test cases:**

```
Input -> output (space-delimited)

"Good afternoon, World!" -> "Wood Gfternoon, aorld!"
"This is a long sentence." -> "shis Ts i aong lentence."
"Programming Puzzles and Code Golf" -> Grogramming Puzzles Pnd aode Colf"
"Input -> output" -> "onput I> -utput"
"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." -> "dhe Tuick qrown box fumped jver ohe tazy log."
"good green grass grows." -> "good green grass grows."
```

Comment: Is a trailing space allowed in the output?

Comment: Can we assume there will be at most one space between words?

Comment: with some rules on which letters can follow each other, you'd have a spoonerism generator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism

Comment: @BusinessCat Yes.

Comment: @mathjunkie Yes.

Comment: The second test case's output appears to be missing a trailing period `.`

Comment: May we take input as a matrix with one word in each column?

Comment: @Adám That is fine.

Comment: It is more a rotate than a swap

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
€ćÁ2ôJ
```

Explanation:

```
€ć      Extract head of each
  Á     Rotate to the right
    2ô  Split into pieces of length two
      J Join
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oac2R9sONRoe3eP3/H63unp@foq6joJ6YVpJalJefnwfihOcX5aQoqscCAA)

Comment: You can take input and output as a list, you know.

Answer (score 9):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

Takes advantage of Japt's index wrapping and negative indexing.

```
ËhUgEÉ g
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=y2hVZ0XJIGc=&input=WyJUaGlzIiwiaXMiLCJhIiwibG9uZyIsInNlbnRlbmNlLiJd)

---

### Explanation

```
        :Implicit input of array U (each element is an individual word).
Ë       :Map over the array.
h       :Replace the first character of the current element (word) ...
Ug      :  with the word in the array at index ...
EÉ      :    current index (E) -1's ...
g       :  first character.
        :Implicit output of array of modified words
```

Comment: I think you can take input as a list as well, saving a further byte on the `¸`

Comment: That might be a stretch, @ETHproductions, but I'll ask. EDIT: Confirmed [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122450/122452?noredirect=1#comment300428_122459)

Comment: Yes, at the very beginning of the post it says "Given a list or delimited string," Not sure how long that's been there though (I guess since the challenge was first posted).

Comment: Nice one! Using `h` was a good idea. I came up with [`£g´Y ¯1 +XÅ`](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=o2e0WSCvMSArWMU=&input=WyJUaGlzIiwiaXMiLCJhIiwibG9uZyIsInNlbnRlbmNlLiJd) which can become [£XhUg´Y ¯1](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=o1hoVWe0WSCvMQ==&input=WyJUaGlzIiwiaXMiLCJhIiwibG9uZyIsInNlbnRlbmNlLiJd) using your technique.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
p%((a:b):r)=(p:b):a%r
_%e=e
(%)=<<head.last
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FcZbCoAgEEDRf1cxDAkK0QKiWUlEjDg9wESmWr/lx@XcWqxzPAY/qidX2rBVs1ohMRs562maDuE4JL6fevGZgaDomR/oYPubUSViDxjSK81dRTIu9QM) Uses a list of strings for input and output.

Remembers the first letter of the previous word `p`, and recursively makes it the first letter of the current word while sending the new first letter down the chain. The previous first letter is initialized as the first letter of the last word.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>85</s> <s>77</s> 63 bytes

Pretty sure this could be much shorter.

Edit: Thanks for @manatwork for collect -> map

```
a=gets.split;$><<a.zip(a.rotate -1).map{|x,y|y[0]+x[1..-1]}*' '
```

Comment: You could replace both `.collect` and `.each` with `.map`.

Comment: `-p` flag (+1 byte) and `i=-2;gsub(r=/\b\w/){$_.scan(r)[i+=1]}` for ultimate golfage

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to jimmy23013

```
q~Sf+:()o
```

Takes input as a list of words.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19YF5ymbaWhmf//f7SSe35@ipKCUmJaSWpRXn5@ng6QE55flJOiqBQLAA)

#### Explanation

```
     e# Example input: ["Good" "afternoon," "World!"]
q~   e# Read and eval the input.
     e# STACK: [["Good" "afternoon," "World!"]]
Sf+  e# Append a space to each word.
     e# STACK: [["Good " "afternoon, " "World! "]]
:(   e# Remove the first character from each substring.
     e# STACK: [["ood " 'G "fternoon, " 'a "orld! " 'W]]
)o   e# Remove and print the last element of the array.
     e# STACK: [["ood " 'G "fternoon, " 'a "orld! "]]
     e# Implicitly join the remaining array with no separator and output.
```

Comment: You can take input and output as a list, you know.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony You confirmed that after I answered :P Golfing it now

Comment: `)o` for `1m>`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Ḣ€ṙ-;"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wx6JHTWse7pypa630/3D70UkPd874/z9a3dFJXUfd2QVIuLqpxwIA)

Thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for reading the rules better than me, this returns a list of the words. It doesn't work as a full program.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

```js
s=>s.map((k,i)=>s.slice(i-1)[0][0]+k.slice(1))
```

Takes advantage of the fact that `slice(-1)` returns the last element of an array.

**Snippet**

```js
f =

s=>s.map((k,i)=>s.slice(i-1)[0][0]+k.slice(1))

console.log(f(['Good', 'afternoon,', 'World!']));
console.log(f(['This', 'is', 'a', 'long', 'sentence.']));
console.log(f(['Programming', 'Puzzles', 'and', 'Code', 'Golf']));
console.log(f(['Input', '->', 'output']));
console.log(f(['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog.']));
console.log(f(['good', 'green', 'grass', 'grows.']));
```

Comment: Could you remove join? Question states that you can output a list. It would save 8 bytes

Comment: @CraigAyre, sweet, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, <s>16</s>, 9 bytes

```
<C-v>GdjPGD{P
```

*7 bytes saved thanks to @Wossname!*

Takes input one word per line, e.g.

```
Hello
world
and
good
day
to
you
```

I believe this should be fine since taking the input as a list is allowed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@y/mnpIV4O5SHfD/f0BRfnpRYm5uZl46V0BpVVVOajFXYl4Kl3N@SiqXe35OGgA)

Comment: It can be done in 12 keystrokes if you do it 'by hand' as it were.  Not sure how to articulate that syntax here or if it's even valid to do that in this puzzle. `^vGdjPGd$ggP`       (where ^v is the [control+v] key combo, just be sure to start with the cursor at the top left and be in command mode)

Comment: @Wossname Ah, that's a great idea! Theres a couple small things I added to save even more bytes (for example, `dd -> D`, `gg -> }`) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I didn't know dd and gg both had shorter versions!  Awesome :)

Comment: How about using the "superscript HTML tags" around the letter v in the code instead of "<C-v>"?  That would make the code look the right length when seen in the Answer.  So your code would look like... <sup>V</sup>GdjPGD{P ... which looks pretty neat when the stackexchange web page formats it properly.

Comment: @wossname Actually, they are not equivalent. They just happen to work in this instance. I'd be happy to explain in more detail in [vim---is---](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40448/vim-golf).

Comment: I see, the curly braces jump around between paragraphs, it works here because we're only dealing with one paragraph.  Cool.  Oh wow that makes scrolling quickly through large code files really easy!  Thanks for that tip. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 7 bytes

```
Îxjp
{P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@4ryKrgKs64P//gKL89KLE3NzMvHSugNKqqpzUYq7EvBQu5/yUVC73/Jw0AA)

Explanation:

```
Î       " On every line:
 x      "   Delete the first character
  j     "   Move down a line
   p    "   And paste a character (into column 2)
{       " Move to the beginning of the input
 P      " And paste the last thing we deleted (into column 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>44</s> 45 bytes

```
90.f3+0.>&i&01.>~r&l0=?;o20.
 i:" "=?^:1+ ?!^
```

Assumes space-separated words.

Correction by Aaron added 1 byte

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 bytes

Takes matrix with one word per column.

```apl
¯1∘⌽@1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///37M8seBR24RD6w0fdcx41LPXwRAipvCobypQ/FHbxGgDPdNYdff8/BR1BfXEtJLUorz8/DwdICc8vygnRVEdAA)

`¯1∘⌽` rotate one step right

`@` at

`1` row 1

Comment: clever input idea

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 74 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DcixCoAgEADQva@4JpVMag2a@wCHBnFQKriIOzFb@nlrevCqnZHSU6Qyd7rwt0kZqQgQ5mQkGd3gu@DGyR@cIegISPBiklZb1//dWTf1o1eqVrEwbxCOsmdiJg0r52trxQc)

```
S=input().split()
print' '.join(b[0]+a[1:]for a,b in zip(S,S[-1:]+S[:-1]))
```

-5 bytes, thanks to @Rod

Comment: @Rod Good suggestion, thank you!

Comment: `S[:-1]` can be shortened to `S`; zipping lists of different lengths automatically truncates whichever is longer

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://haskell.org), 50 bytes

```hs
f=zipWith(:).((:).last<*>init).map head<*>map tail
```

Input and output are as lists of words.

Comment: Functions can be unnamed, so you can omit the `f=`.

Comment: Oh, cool, I didn't realize there was an online compiler for Haskell. I'll delete my comments, since I'm wrong ^^

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>72</s> 70 bytes

`function(x)paste0(substr(x,1,1)[c(y<-length(x),2:y-1)],substring(x,2))`

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Jco7CsMwDADQq7SeJFCgzhjaOUfoUDrkY6cGIwVbgeT0rkPGBy@V4l9@40mDMOy4DlndA/I2Zk2wkyWLnwmOZxMdL/qrhdruaCx@6UqBl/paxOIhhqxgepHZ0M0MXl1iEaZTb0lxvpv6yh8)

2 bytes saved thanks to Giuseppe.

Input and output are lists. Takes a substring consisting of the first letters, cycles the last one to the front, and pastes it together with a substring of the rest of each word. The cycling step is a killer, but I can't figure out a way to cut it down any further.

Comment: you could use `2:y-1` instead of `1:(y-1)` since `:` takes precedence over `-` which saves you 2 bytes.

Comment: [69 bytes aliasing `substring` as a function argument](https://tio.run/##FYrNCsIwDIBfpfaUQAZ2R5lnH8GDeJhbOwslkSaD7enrdvx@aktu6FxLK0@WhWEjvev6UauZF/yNavEKeuhAAV8T7ENXIi/2hQ2pv@1dwDedvUdsCUpWA/8QmT05PyaLlUWYTnpKLfPFH1/7Aw "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2 + Numpy, 104 bytes

```
from numpy import *
s=fromstring(input(),"b")
m=roll(s==32,1)
m[0]=1
s[m]=roll(s[m],1)
print s.tobytes()
```

Comment: You need to include the import statement in the byte count. Cool answer!

Comment: also, you need to have your input and output code in the byte count

Comment: I think you can drop the final newline for 1 byte.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen yes, also "b" instead of "u1" works, so -2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 62 bytes

```
$c=end($_GET);foreach($_GET as$g)echo$g|$g[0]=$c^$g^$c=$g,' ';
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>78</s> 77 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;a=>a.Select((s,i)=>a[i-->0?i:a.Count-1][0]+s.Substring(1));
```

Compiles to a `Func<List<string>, IEnumerable<string>>`, Full/Formatted version:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<List<string>, IEnumerable<string>> f = a =>
                a.Select((s, i) => a[i-- > 0 ? i : a.Count - 1][0] + s.Substring(1));

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", f(new List<string>() { "Good", "afternoon,", "World!" })));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", f(new List<string>() { "This", "is", "a", "long", "sentence." })));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
{hᵐ↻|bᵐ}ᶠzcᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@1@d8XDrhEdtu2uSgHTtw20LqpKBjP//o5Xc8/NTlHSUEtNKUovy8vPzdICc8PyinBRFpdj/UQA)

#### Explanation

```
Example input: ["Good","afternoon,","World!"]

{      }ᶠ       Find: [["W","G","a"],["ood","fternoon,","orld!"]]
 hᵐ↻              Take the head of each string, cyclically permute them
    |             (and)
     bᵐ           Get the strings without their heads
         z      Zip: [["W","ood"],["G","fternoon,"],["a","orld!"]]
          cᵐ    Map concatenate on each list: ["Wood","Gfternoon,","aorld!"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$13\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 10.701 bytes

```
j/ +e[qJ]xxep
```

*-2.469 bytes thanks to one of the @Sʨɠɠans*

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJqLyArZVtxSl14eGVwIiwiW1N3YXAsIHRoZSwgZmlyc3QsIGxldHRlcnNdIl0=)

Explanation:

```
       J       # Append
          x    # the input
        ]x     # to the first item from the input,
      q        # then remove the first item from that.
    e[         # Get the first character from each item.
           ep  # Get the input with the first char of each word removed.
   +           # Add,
j              # join by
 /             # space
```

Comment: you can replace `" "` with `/ `

Comment: [13 chars](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJqLyArZVtxSl14eGVwIiwiW1N3YXAsIHRoZSwgZmlyc3QsIGxldHRlcnNdIl0=) by replacing `M@<op>` with `e<op>`

Comment: I should probably repurpose `:` as a reverse lazy op...

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>46</s> <s>37</s> 31 bytes

*Several bytes saved thanks to @Neil and @PunPun1000*

```
(\S)(\S* +)
$2$1
(.* .)(.)
$2$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU7LasNADLzvV0wgATttFtIPyKUH01ughV566CYrb9yupXQfTeKfdxUKo2E0GsQkKgO77bxqus@5@XhtddZ4aM3yabk1jV3Dto39X@e5E/FwfaHEIvyId0nRL8zbachQOEThgExciI9kzT5JSG4cB3X3dZoiaYg9nsUTOom9eeFzLdjsILWo0leEnzocv3FIcmH0csVXHc/kIb@UUPQe3XSDl2BNuPcJiYiVXc7Kcsn2Dw)

Comment: Can you not drop the `(.*)` and `$3`?

Comment: @Neil yeah, thanks

Comment: If you turn the `+` in the first line to a `*` you turn `(.* .)` in the third line to `(.*)` for -2 bytes.  [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##JU7LasNADLzvV0whB9s0C8kH9NJD6M2QQC@5bLPy1s1aSvbRpP55R6EwGkajQUyiMrJblua4b3U6dK1ZbVcb09iubez/siw7EQ83FEoswq/4lBT9izl8jxkKhygckIkL8Yms6ZOE5KZpVLev8xxJQ@zxLp6wkziYD77UgvUbpBZV@opwrePpjK8kN8Ygd/zU6UIe8ksJRe/RzX/wEqwJzz4hEbGyy1lZbtk@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## kdb+, <s>25</s> 22 bytes

**Solution:**

```
rotate[-1;1#'a],'1_'a:
```

**Example:**

```
q)rotate[-1;1#'a],'1_'a:("The";"quick";"brown";"fox";"jumped";"over";"the";"lazy";"dog.")
"dhe"
"Tuick"
"qrown"
"box"
"fumped"
"jver"
"ohe"
"tazy"
"log."
```

**Explanation:**

```
1_'a:             // (y) drop first character of each element of a
,'                // join each left with each right
rotate[-1;1#'a]   // (x) take first character of each element of a, rotate backwards 1 char
```

**Extra:**

A version that takes a regular string (37 bytes):

```
q){" "sv rotate[-1;1#'a],'1_'a:" "vs x}"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
"dhe Tuick qrown box fumped jver ohe tazy log."
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 59 bytes

```
""<>#&/@Thread@{RotateRight@#~StringTake~1,#~StringDrop~1}&
```

[Try it online!](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/)

Takes and returns a list of words.

If you prefer to take and return strings, this works for 87 bytes:

```
StringRiffle[Thread@{RotateRight@#~StringTake~1,#~StringDrop~1}&@StringSplit@#," ",""]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 40 bytes

39 bytes of code + 1 for `-a`

```perl
$F[-1]=~/./;$a=$&,s/./$a/ for@F;say"@F"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FLVrXMNa2Tl9P31ol0VZFTacYyFRJ1FdIyy9ycLMuTqxUcnBT@v/fPT8/RSExrSS1KC8/P09HITy/KCdF8V9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/uokA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 34 bytes

```
;@(,.~_1|.])~/@|:@(split;.2)@,&' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU7NSgMxGLzvU4wXt4VtRI8WS6BgETz0IHgSiZsvaWo235ofq0vpq68RhmGYGYY5zrN5EFjLRScu77dn8ba83MjzvVyk0bu8FndL2V23aGfqDyyN3KAv@fkRKWsX0LbzjllDmUwxMIcOrxy9vmpeDi6hQsFzsEgUMoWeRLOPbKMaBlfdfZkmT7UUNLasCTv2pnkKY8lYbcAlV1WnCF/F9Z/4iHwKMPyDYxlG0uBvisg192r6hWYrGvv/x0aiUFmlVJlPSfwB)

Comment: `;@(,&' '@}.&.>,~&.>_1|.{.&>)@cut` for 32.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
Foz:ṙ_1TmΓ,
```

Input and output as a list of strings, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5f/qipsfy/W36V1cOdM@MNQ3LPTdb5//9/SEaqQmFpZnK2QlJRfnmeQlp@hUJWaW5BaopCfllqkUIJUD4nsapSISU/XQ8A)

<sub>(The header just transforms the input to a list of words and joins the output list with spaces.)</sub>

#### Explanation

```
F(z:ṙ_1)TmΓ,  -- example input: ["Good" "afternoon,","World!"]
         m    -- map the following (example on "Good")
          Γ   -- | pattern match head & tail: 'G' "ood"
           ,  -- | construct tuple: ('G',"ood")
              -- : [('G',"ood"),('a',"fternoon,"),('W',"orld!")]
        T     -- unzip: ("GaW",["ood","fternoon,","orld!"])
F(     )      -- apply the function to the pair
    ṙ_1       -- | rotate first argument by 1 (to right): "WGa"
  z:          -- | zip the two by (example with 'W' and "ood")
              -- | | cons/(re)construct string: "Wood"
              -- :-: ["Wood","Gfternoon,","aorld!"]
```

#### Alternative, 11 bytes

```
§oz:ṙ_1m←mt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5f/qipsfz/oeX5VVYPd86MN8x91DYht@T///8hGakKhaWZydkKSUX55XkKafkVClmluQWpKQr5ZalFCiVA@ZzEqkqFlPx0PQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `S`, 7 bytes

```
vhǔ?vḢ+
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJTIiwiIiwidmjHlD924biiKyIsIiIsIltcIlN3YXBcIiwgXCJ0aGVcIiwgXCJmaXJzdFwiLCBcIkxldHRlcnNcIl0iXQ==)

```
vh       # Get the first item of each
  ǔ      # Rotate to the right
   ?     # Push the input
    vḢ   # Get the all but the first char of each
      +  # Add
```

Comment: you can do `vhǔ?vḢ+` and remove the `r` flag.

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan True, thank you

Answer (score 0):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>25</s> 20 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
Om$`^.((?=.*¶))?
$#1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#FU5LagJBFNz3KSpoYNSkIQeILrIQVwoRshGxY7/pjPa8p/3xMwfzALnYpANFUVQVRT1Xn7tNnPTLdrjb6qqavevx72M0mqnh4K3fsEI/F7EwdaLAIvyCLwnePqn1TxNRYOCFHSJxIt6TVqsgLpi2bYq7yl3nqZTY4kMsYS6@Vgs@5YTXKSSnosoU4Zyb/RHfQa6MWm445PZEFnKhgFRyb7o7rDit3P8fF4i4sImxsFyj/gM)

Input and output are linefeed-separated. The test suite performs the necessary I/O conversion from space-separation.

Comment: It is fine to use linefeed separation.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 134 bytes

```
(w=Characters@StringSplit@#;d=Drop[w,0,1];StringRiffle[StringJoin/@Table[PrependTo[d[[i]],RotateRight[First/@w][[i]]],{i,Length@w}]])&
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>106</s> 77 bytes

```
i,a,b;f(char*o){a=*o;for(i=0;o[i++];)if(o[i]==32){b=o[++i];o[i]=a;a=b;}*o=a;}
```

-29 bytes from scottinet

Modifies the string in-place.

Ungolfed:

```
char *f(char *o){
    char a=*o,b; // start with a as the first character of the first word
    for(int i=0;++i<strlen(o);){
        // iterate through the string with i as the index
        if(o[i]==32){ // if the current character is a space, 
                      // i.e. if a word begins after this character
            b=o[++i]; // store the beginning of the next word in b
            o[i]=a; // set the beginning of the next word to a
            a=b; // set a to what the beginning of the next work used to be
        }
    }
    *o=a; 
    // set the beginning of the first word to the old beginning of the last word
}
```

Comment: Golfier version proposal (exact same code): [-29 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc1BDsIgFATQq9SuoGBidPnz1x7BBWHxoaIk2mmwrpqeHVF3L5PJTNzfYqw1W7GBkop3KQP0KjyAEorKfCC4bIwnnZNq9Myno14DwxmTPf0iIeFA24CmrT4lT0qv37EuAc5zfwbGTtJyLRMw2e6C8hh3fbtsBU3ze3n9tdUP "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY1BCsIwFESvUrtKmghFd34@Lj2Ci5DFT2o0oB2JdVV69lh1NcNjeBO31xhrzVZsoKTiTUoHPQt3oISiMvcEl43xpNf0zPvdMTCcMdnbHxErHA49dWChpT4kj0rPX1OTAOe5PQFDI2m6lBEYbXNGuQ@bdv1bB5qe7@n1b0v9AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
.b+hNtY.>Q1Q
```

Takes a list of words and returns a list of words.

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.b%2BhNtY.%3EQ1Q&input=%5B%27Good%27%2C+%27afternoon%2C%27%2C+%27World%21%27%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 97 bytes

```java
for(int n=s.length,i=0,j=n-1;i<n;j%=n)System.out.print(s[j++].charAt(0)+s[i++].substring(1)+" ");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY6xDoJAEER7v2I1MbkLSLBGCisrKwsLQnEC6p24S24XEkP49hOM00zyJjMZZwazo65BV79C199aW0HVGmY4G4swrmDWn7MYmW0gW8N7TtVFvMVHUQJrGMOdvLIogDknbYMPecY2T2OX426f2QNmbpujvnxYmndCvSTd3BbFhYuiMqmexh9FpTriwi6A@xv/9tVeRxvY6CwsX6bVFMKJqA7mLo1HIozDlXxbr78)

Comment: This is a snippet, not a function. Also, you should take the entire String as one argument, and also keep commas and question/examination marks in the output as is.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 63 bytes

```
{for(R=substr($NF,1,1);++j<=NF;R=r)sub(r=substr($j,1,1),R,$j)}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BS8QwEIXv/RUj7KFlY7HnWi/CLl6WpQies5tpbDadWSeJ1Yq/vUYPwuPxmPcxPD1f1vVrYCn7LqRTiFJuDjvVqKZqt1t33x12bd9JlbtS/gn3B6hebVzVuu7uu1nXPbMBPUQUYiYFLyze3BTPr2OALA2eyUJAikhnrIujsBU9TWO@HtOyeMwQGXhkg7BnPxRPdE0Rbh@AU8wpv0J4S@P5AifhmWDgD3BpuqIBfkeBmHuvl08wbOvC/u6xgkjZdQjZeQ71Dw)

It seems like there should be a way to reduce the redundancy, but I'm not seeing it.

Note: the TIO link has 4 extra bytes to allow for multiline input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes

```python
lambda s:' '.join(s.split()[i-1][0]+w[1:]for i,w in enumerate(s.split()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZCxbsIwEIb3PMU1SxI1iUDdkGBhQGwMSAyUweBLMHV8wXZI4eXpmaCytJJl2fd/3@ns9uqPZD7u1fTzrkWzlwLcJIGkPJEyqStdq5VPs60qxrvtaPfeb8eTXUUWVN6DMoCma9AKjy82y@4B0MpgIKhFk46ySQR8a3OgzsMUGtGmeBE6f3ClHdykmCU5jLOMYYuOuSplKVxbq4xPuTidcoc8xNk9XhBJEJVHa4hMDhuyWr7FUMwg3oRs8crEkEXx@qgc8BKgydTg0Hg0BywHzYV0zQALnOrfNIpXlmormkZxfdXdbppHFEbCnCTCgnQ1dFj8ga0YEwGbByyKl6blf2CaH8OnQaRHcTmDYiiGURHOnTp8wd5Sb6Cibzh1TYsS6IIWPOda3K4gqX7OL7m0fijnh7JnpRqUU1CIcx8UHZQorsM31RbR8C6c451692z2X/gD)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 129 bytes

```rust
|k:&str|k.split(' ').zip(k.split(' ').cycle().skip(k.matches(' ').count())).map(|(a,b)|[&b[0..1],&a[1..]," "].concat()).collect()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVBLThwxEFW2fYrCi8GWGhN20YwIC6QgdkiJFCmj0cjTXW4643Z1_IHMb5FzsJkFHCDHgdNg9yCiWFZV2e9V-fk9PLrow_6vttCp1nIBG4MB9PlTDPrk0_Of7XI88sFtl9L3pg38GI6FXLc9_--iWlUGuZB-OSCdCtUt-jeMog1cCJGue77lqlyI7XS0mH6U8mxWjtT0TMpZyYDNEtdWKpNTZQxWqTwIefnwY1JkZfM4hq_BtbaBc9CcqQUTEzg9hS_kIKx6hNZqdGgrBNLwPqYodCagD_NK-cyCaQFpsSuiGpQO6CyRLeE7OVMfsbJg325bD2krMJTe82hDnisZJPDGUeNU12UlN3G9NpiItoZLqhGuyOiBdW37GODkM1AMqTpMRfgV22oJC0f3FjT9hp-x67EGusOkMeFGrVdQUyNzQ5MFNg7Rpqi8T5HuvWSD_BlshtwnS4KxR5xpvhlf7ESyJ2dW_vt0mQx7PwgxGRp3xe5g8X5_yK8)

Shifting the other direction would be a *lot* shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
€ḢṾ2ẇ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

Port of Okx's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
€ḢṾ2ẇ  # Implicit input
€Ḣ     # Head extract from each
  Ṿ    # Rotate right once
   2ẇ  # Split into pairs
       # Join on spaces
       # Implicit output
```